# Can I make auto complete to android's default Searchbar?

Tags: android

I'm trying to do an autocomplete for android's default search dialog but it doesn't seem to work. Is this impossible to do?

Answer (score 1):

After some research i found that YES it can be done and here's how it's done:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html